Getting "TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable" while using disnake
I have a function that is responsible for issuing warnings to the user. Here it is:
warnings = {}


@bot.command()
@commands.has_role(1247956039404486720)
async def warn(ctx, member: disnake.Member, *, reason: str):
    if member not in warnings:
        warnings[member] = []
    warnings[member].append((ctx.author, reason, datetime.datetime.now()))
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been warned for: {reason}.")

    log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
    await log_channel.send(f"{member} has been warned by {ctx.author} for: {reason}.")

According to the idea, it should save all warnings, but when you try to use it, the following error appears:
    if member not in warnings:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable

I would be very grateful if you could tell me the solutions :)

Can you try using a different variable name instead of warnings? You have not shared the complete code. It's possible either Python's warnings module import or similarly named import from disnake is declared somewhere in your code which is overriding your variable. Or there could be some other function that is named warnings.
